# Microstrategy - Creating 3 selectors on the same attribute

Tags: microstrategy

I have a requirement of comparing Product line (attribute) and Brand (Attribute) using 3 different selectors. Product line and Brand is having one to one relationship .

My dashboard should look like below.(sorry I cant attach the snapshot)

Prod line (selector)  Brand(selector)

Prod line (selector)  Brand(selector)

Prod line (selector)  Brand(selector)

These selectors should be only dropdown type.

User will select a particular product line and can compare it with a particular brand at a time.

I created 3 selectors with the same attributes , but it is not working.
Please help me with the above scenario ASAP. We suggested the checkbox type selector but the client requirement is only dropdown

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Do you want one selector to target your other selectors? So if you select a product line on one, the product line on the others is filtered too?

Comment: Sagar can you try to clarify? are you trying to show different product lines/brands in a grid below the selector? can you show a mock-up of your dashboard?

Comment: Hi , I want to show different product lines and their corresponding brands using selectors only.

Comment: EG. Product A  ---- Brand A ,   Product B --- Brand B , Product C -- Brand C......   see I have to show all these comparison using 3 selectors for Product line and 3 selector for Brand...I cant use grid or anything...

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar scenario (a bit easier, only [Region]->[Street] in the dataset and we wanted to select two streets from this region from and target a single panel).

What we ended up with: Creating additional attributes. These attributes must not be built on the same table so you have to create aliases for that.
You'd end up with "lu_product", "lu_product_alias1" and "lu_product_alias2". Then just copy the Product attribute twice and alter the id/desc-attribute forms to point to the correct alias-table. If this doesn't help you might have to repeat the process for Brand.

Personally I think this brute-force solution is insane, but it worked for us and a small dataset. I'd be glad to see other and more lightweight solutions though.